# Cloudformation Snippet To Connect To Hosted Chef

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, chef-infra, chef-solo, aws-cloudformation

Can't seem to find a code snippet to run a Cloudformation template 
on Ubuntu 14.10 and connect to hosted chef.

I am able to download and run cfn-init, "AWS::CloudFormation::Init".  Also, I have my organization-validator.pem file and my client.pem file.

I found this example based on [Amazon linux](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-templates-us-west-2/WordPress_Chef.template) as a guide, but not quite sure how to transition it to Ubuntu.  Thoughts?

Comment: It  likes a consultant job you are asking. I am fine if you pay me to do that. But from your point, i recommend to read more documents regarding `how cloudformation template works`. the template is suitable for your current requirement, you just need to understand each part of it, and do the adjust for your own environment.

Comment: @BMW:  Thanks for mentioning.  Is there some base requirements to call the hosted chef server?  What I was thinking is there is an installation of chef-client, then running a chef-client executable with the keys to the hosted chef server at chef.io.   I've been hacking at the docs and my template json file, but not sure how close I'm getting.

Answer (score 0):

This is way out of scope for a single answer, but I have an example over at https://github.com/coderanger/brix. The `packer/` subdir shows how to build the AMI to use with EC2 (though you would want to change https://github.com/coderanger/brix/blob/master/packer/client.rb#L3 and the relevant keys). https://github.com/coderanger/brix/blob/master/templates/base.py#L224-L249 shows the launch config, it is a custom-ish DSL but hopefully it is still readable.

Comment: Is there a way to translate the code executed by https://github.com/coderanger/brix/blob/master/packer/client.rb#L3 something that could be placed in the template file?  It seems this link has the base lines of code as variables, meaning they make sense, but how would that look in the template file?   Bye the way, I'm using a bare (json) based template, a bit brutal, but still new at this.

Comment: I don't know what code you mean, that line is just a plain config file that gets written in to the AMI.